# add "back" button to a form in ploneformgen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I have a multipage form in Plone using ploneformgen. I would like the user to be able to navigate back with a back button. Can someone please point how can I add a back button to my form?

Comment: Multi-page ploneformgens do not work well. The browser back button should work yet though as browsers will re-fill forms when hitting the back button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a trivial way to do this in PFG, but you could use http://plone.org/products/collective.z3cform.wizard.  Warning: this is not point-and-click configuration.